# Mixed number class istream issues

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, fractions, iomanip

I assigned myself some homework over the summer, and the project I am 98% finished with has come to a standstill due to this one problem.

I have a class called Mixed. It contains member data for a whole number, a numerator, and a denominator. I need to overload all of the common operators to allow multiplication, addition, comparison and streaming of objects of type Mixed. I have all the operators overloaded except for >> (the extraction operator).

All mixed numbers read in will be of format:
**whole numerator/denominator**

ex: 1 2/3, 0 7/8, -3 18/5, 0 -1/89

Header: `friend istream& operator>> (istream &, Mixed);`

CPP file: `istream& operator>> (istream &in, Mixed m) {...}`

For the assignment, I am limited to the iostream and iomanip libraries. My plan was to read in the values from the stream and assign them to temporary int variables (w, n, d) which I would then use with the Mixed constructor to create object m. Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to separate the numerator and denominator. They are both ints, but they have a char (/) between them.

- I cannot use getline() with its delimiter, because it assigns data to a char array, which I do not believe I can convert to an int without another library.
- I cannot use a char array and then segment it for the same reason.
- I cannot use a while loop with get() and peek() because, again, I do not think I will be able to convert a char array into an int.
- I cannot use a string or c-string and then segment it because that requires external libraries.

Once again, I need to split a value like "22/34" into 22 and 34, using only iostream and iomanip. Is there some fairly obvious method I am overlooking? Is there a way to implicitly convert using pointers?

Comment: Will you allow yourself to use `stringstream` and `string`?

Comment: If you look in the `<complex>` header, there is an example of reading the format `(22,34)`. Could be used as an inspiration!

Comment: @jrok: No, I am only to use iostream and iomanip.

One workaround I thought of, would be to somehow read the stream contents twice, as in copying the stream object, or seeking to the beginning after the first read.

I can easily make the program work by using strings, segmenting them, and convert to int. But again, the assignment should be able to (since it was in the instructions) be completed using only iostream and iomanip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first extract the nominator, then the separating character, and then the denominator.

Example for illustration:

```
istream& operator>> (istream &in, Mixed &m) {
    int num, denom;
    char separ;

    in >> num;
    in.get(separ);
    if (separ != '/')
      in.setstate(ios::failbit);
    in >> denom;

    if (in) {
      // All extraction worked
      m.numerator = num;
      m.denominator = denom;
    }

    return in;
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that doing something like in >> num would read in an entire block of characters, only ignoring whitespaces, resulting in the entire fraction casted as a single int.

Answer (score 0):

> Once again, I need to split a value like "22/34" into 22 and 34, using
>   only iostream and iomanip.

Couldn't you just read in the first integer, use `get` to get the next character, and then read the second integer?  Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;

    int num;
    int den;

    while(cin) {
        cin >> num;
        if (cin.get() != '/') {
            // handle error
        }   
        cin >> den;

        cout << num << "/" << den << std::endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

You can then make sure that the character read between the two integers was a `'/'` and handle appropriately if it isn't.